# Different versions of PHP different results of crypt ()

Tags: php, crypt

Code:

```
echo $a = 'stackoverflow';
echo '<br>';
echo $b = '$2a$10$bf57caf7e1fa23e4b975ab';
echo '<br>CRYPT:<br>';
echo crypt($a, $b);
```

Results:

**PHP 5.2.5**

```
stackoverflow
$2a$10$bf57caf7e1fa23e4b975ab
CRYPT:
$2.LaeiP21fsQ
```

**PHP 5.4.4**

```
stackoverflow
$2a$10$bf57caf7e1fa23e4b975ab
CRYPT:
$2a$10$bf57caf7e1fa23e4b975aOhXjTtYrqOYLfHsxdOxGRhF03.LtKewW
```

I want to move the script to a new server with PHP 5.4.4
I would like to get the same effect as the 5.2.5 hashes, otherwise I will lose some data

If I use salt with ending $ - the result is the same

I read this:

> As of PHP 5.3.0, PHP contains its own implementation and will use that
>   if the system lacks of support for one or more of the algorithms.

But the algorithm should not be different.

Please help.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://www.php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php

Comment: I found this http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60073&edit=1

Comment: That bug you linked to ... is not a bug.  Read the bottom of the file for the explanation showing that. >> "You got this output on earlier 
versions of PHP where CRYPT_BLOWFISH was not supported, or perhaps a buggy version 
was being used."

Answer (score 1):

Prior to PHP 5.3.0, Blowfish was only available if your system's C library provided it (and almost no one's did). Passing a Blowfish salt in systems that don't have a Blowfish implementation results in a crapshoot of algorithm selection - usually, a DES hash.